# getting the error "String index out of range : 0" when trying to implement a simple calculator in java

Tags: java, recursion, calculator

Getting this error after calling the input function just after the calc function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ques20part2 {
public static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {

    input();
}
public static void input(){
    char c = scn.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if(c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '%'){
        int n1 = scn.nextInt();
        int n2 = scn.nextInt();
        System.out.println(calc(c, n1, n2));
        input();
```

the problem is here^

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

at  java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)

at  assignment_3.ques20part2.input(ques20part2.java:12)

at  assignment_3.ques20part2.main(ques20part2.java:9)

at  assignment_3.ques20part2.input(ques20part2.java:17)

at  assignment_3.ques20part2.main(ques20part2.java:9)

```
    }else if(c == 'x' || c == 'X'){
        System.exit(0);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Invalid operation. Try again.");
        input();
    }   
}

public static int calc(char c,int n1,int n2){
    int val = 0;
    switch(c){
    case '+' :
        val = n1 + n2;
        break;
    case '-' :
        val = n1 - n2;
        break;
    case '*' :
        val = n1 * n2;
        break;
    case '/' :
        val = n1 / n2;
        break;
    case'%' :
        val = n1%n2;
        break;
}
    return val;

}
}
```

Comment: Well presumably `nextLine()` returned an empty string...

Comment: i used char c = scn.next().charAt(0); and it worked.thanks! :)

Comment: I think it's because nextInt will read until the number is finished. Thus if you enter `"+\n4\n5\n"`  it will print `9`. If you do nextLine the next this is a linefeed so the next line will be "" and it does not have a char at index 0.

Comment: How about adding an if(scn.hasNextLine()) { char c = scn.nextLine().charAt(0);/*... rest of code...*/} . See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html